# How to get Data from Realm for my ListView

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I have a problem, in my first screen **LaunchScreen**, i have a button for adding some data in my Realm :

```
addBdd(realm){
 realm.write(() => {
  realm.create('Bills', {
    type: "Fournitures",
    creditor: "Entreprise A",
    month: "Avril",
    year: "2017",
    price: "40",
  })
});
 alert("Count : " + realm.objects('Bills').length);
}
```

All is working this far. But after that, i have two views, a **LoginScreen**, and the View where data must be applied to my list view : **ListBillScreen**

```
<ListView
    enableEmptySections={true}
    style={styles.listView}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} navigator={this.props.navigator} />}
    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
  />
```

Which calls a class named **Row** :

```
function goBillscreen() {
props.navigator.push({ screen: 'BillScreen', props: {
billType : props.type,
billCreditor : props.creditor,
billMonth : props.month,
billYear: props.year,
billPrice: props.price
}});
}

return(
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => goBillscreen()}>
<View style={styles.container}>
<Image source={{ uri: props.picture}} style={styles.photo} />
<Text style={styles.text}>
  {`${props.type} ${props.creditor} / ${props.month} ${props.year}`}
  {`\n${props.price} euros`}
</Text>
</View>
</TouchableHighlight>
);
```

The question is : How do I give my realm to the ListBillView to give the data like :

```
this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(datafromrealm)
};
```

and how can I give type, creditor, month, year and price to **Row** ?

Sorry for the long post I tried but I'm lost !

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the question is not well defined but seems you are asking how to process data for every row in your listview. You can check some of the examples we have in realm-js repo like this one

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/todo-listview.js#L85

This is a  todo list sample application which uses a ListView to show the todo items.